# div text exceeds parent's width

Tags: css, angular

[img of what is actually happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRQxb.png)

[image]

Basically, there is a div which its text is exceeding its maximum width. Ive already tried to set `max-width:100%` (to see if it sets the maximum width to parent's full width) in more or less 10 parent divs but the problem is still happening. Also, ive already looked for some similar posts in here and most of them tell me to use `white-space:normal` but it actually breaks a new line for every word.

In the example below, you can find 3 fields, the first one is the "normal" one, and the others are with `white-space:normal`.

The source code doesn't seem to have any problems with it:

```
<fieldset data-type="horizontal" *ngIf="poll.type == 'Opção'">
    <label translate>Escolher Opção:</label>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="btn-group form-vote" data-toggle="buttons">
            <div class="btn btn-block" *ngFor="let option of poll.options" [ngClass]="{'active': isChosenOption(poll.pollId, option.optionId)}">
                <div class="btn-circle btn-success" (click)="registerOptionVote(poll.pollId, option.optionId)">
                    <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-check': isChosenOption(poll.pollId, option.optionId)}"></i>
                    <div style="white-space: normal;"> {{option.description}} </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cadorealves/9yhLxmz6/

Comment: add css of your page too to your question

Comment: Added in the JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Problem the second div get witdh of btn-cirlce.

You should move out the div

`<div style="white-space: normal;"> {{option.description}} </div>`

of  `<div class="btn-circle btn-success"`

Set `.btn-circle` and `.description` as `inline-block`

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/z87ar50e/5/

Comment: it worked except for just one thing, the texdt is now not showing anymore. im not sure what exactly made it but you can see the screenshot:

https://i.imgur.com/GO23Emj.png

i took a look at F12 and the code is not rendering the `div.description`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

white-space: pre-wrap